# java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol

Tags: java, url, jaxb, xjc

I' m writing a class to run xjc in java. my code goes as follows:

```
 URL url = new URL("C:\\Users\\Simran\\Desktop\\books.xsd"); 
 SchemaCompiler sc = XJC.createSchemaCompiler();
 sc.parseSchema(new InputSource(url.toExternalForm()));
 S2JJAXBModel model = sc.bind();
 JCodeModel cm = model.generateCode(null, null);
 cm.build(new FileCodeWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Simran\\Desktop\\books.xsd")));
```

however I get the following error when I run this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: books.xsd
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at jaxbTest.Test1.main(Test1.java:22)
```

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: Have you tried `sc.parseSchema(new InputSource("C:\\Users\\Simran\\Desktop\\books.xsd"));` As I suggested before ?

Comment: ya i had tried this & it didnt work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try append `"file://"` to the beginning of your file path. But as Bozho proposed, you don't need an URL here.

Comment: +1, mentioned the `file://` protocol while I was adding it to my answer :)

Comment: can anyone give me some link for using xjc through API calls?

Comment: oh, please mark some answer as accepted and ask another question. Don't use comments for that.

Comment: but in ubuntu ?

Answer (score 11):

This is not a valid URL. It can be made valid by prepending `file://` as protocol.

But you don't need a URL at all. You can pass a `Reader` (as well as an `InputStream`) to the `InputSource` constructor. So for example:

```
new InputSource(new FileReader(path))
```

Comment: i always thought that it was with three /'s, like file:///, but am upvoting this answer.  also the correct term is not appending but prepending.

Comment: thanks for the "prepending". It works with two slashes as well, I'm not sure which is the standard. I guess it gets normalized regardless of the number of slashes.

Answer (score -4):

I had the above ,while opening the virtual console.

Resolution : You have select very secure option in Browser.

Start--> Java configuration -->Security --Cilick on - Very High.