# Malformed URL exception while using GSON

Tags: java, gson

I am using GSON to parse JSON data. Here is my code -

```
public class TestProg {

private static final String storeURL = "https://abcd"; //Haven't given the URL here completely

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String getData = getDataFromURL(storeURL);      
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Test rs = (Test) gson.fromJson(getData.toString(), Test.class);

    List<TestB> testData = rs.getContent();
    for(TestB retStr:testData)
    {
        System.out.println(retStr.getTitle());
        System.out.println(retStr.getOwner());

    }

}

public static String getDataFromURL(String url) throws Exception {
    String dataFromURL = readUrl(url);
    return dataFromURL;
}

public static String readUrl(String inputURL) throws IOException {
        URL url = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(inputURL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            System.out.println("Failed : HTTP error code :" + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.print("Exception occured while reading data from the URL "+ e.getMessage()); 
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (br != null)
            br.close();
        conn.disconnect();
    }

}
}
```

I am getting the below error when I run the code -

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: www.abc.com
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:818)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
```

I can't include the Test classes here since it has some sensitive data.

Comment: did you forget the `http(s)://` before `www.`? Some other related questions: [forgot file.//](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556814/java-net-malformedurlexception-no-protocol)

Comment: Are you using some tokens in your Url ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a small edit in your readUrl(String inputURL) Method:

```
    try {
        //Edit starts
        String finalUrl;
        if(!(url.startsWith("http://"))&&!(url.startsWith("https://")))
          {
            finalUrl = "http://"+url;
          }
        //Edit Ends
        url = new URL(finalURL);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

This way, every time before sending the request your url will be modified, it it is malformed.

Comment: Just to be sure: use `startsWith` instead of `contains`? And what if it is not `http://` but `https://`? I would say, the best way to handle such a thing is to handle the error and let the user know that the URL is not a correct URL.

Comment: Nope that didn't help :( I am printing out the getData to be sure I am getting the data from the URL. In the output, I see the correct URL, but when I parse that data using gson, and store it in class Test, the code breaks, and throws the error.

Comment: Provide more details on test. Just obfuscate the sensitive data.

Comment: Are you using some tokens in your Url ?
Like Access_token or something ?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest. Let me check.

Comment: Thanks Salman. I will update you once I find out. It is a production application, so I am assuming we are using it. I have no idea how to check though. I will figure it out, and let you know :)

Comment: Sure. if you find out that token, then just encode that token string and attach it to the url, it will work that way.